# How to install Ubuntu in USB to boot in a Mac system?

Tags: mac, usb-creator

Hello everyone I have a quick question. I'm interested in Ubuntu and would like to put Ubuntu on a 32GB USB drive I have so I can boot it on my mac 10.8.4.

I don't have room on my local drive at the moment so it would need to be self contained on the usb drive itself. Would someone be willing to help me with this if possible?

I've seen similar questions but not with the whole of ubuntu on the usb itself.

Answer (score 0):

On windows I would use a program called "iso to usb". I would burn the iso to the usb key using that. Then I would setup the bios to boot from that. On Macs though, you cannot do this. The efi on macs wont let you boot from a USB key nor is there a similar program to "iso to usb" for macs. So, the only option you got is to get an external dvd rewritable or whatever ... drive, and burn ubuntu linux to a disc using that. What I am saying is based on the suggestion given on the wiki.ubuntu site. SEE, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOnMac